# Unable to access Google Play store and Google Maps

Tags: google-play-store, google-account, google, google-maps, google-apps

I'm not able to access play store and maps with my google account, but it remains accessible with another google account.
I'm at a loss how to resolve this. Would anyone have any solution?

[image: image of Google requiring authentication for unknown reasons]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To try to resolve this, open a web browser and log into the Google Play store for your Google account by going to this URL:

https://play.google.com/store/account

When you do this, Google will request authentication information.  Once you provide this information, Google may allow you back into your own account again.  Or they may not; it's entirely up to their problematic systems which are documented incorrectly in their help database.

Google is infamous for locking people out of their own accounts, even when they provide their passwords.

Comment: This worked like a charm! I've been trying to find a solution for this since yesterday. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome!  I'm glad to help, and I'm happy to hear it worked.  I'm not sure if you have sufficient reputation to upvote yet, but you can upvote helpful answers.  One thing I've learned as a general technique is to try to access anything broken from a different angle, such as from a web browser or a different OS.  That technique has helped me get out of jams a few times.